# Google column chart draw with different value in the single bar

Tags: google-visualization

I have 2 set of data named as data1 and data2. data1 is considered as baseline. data2 is considered as current value. I have to draw a bar chart with below equation.

If data2 < data1 then draw a bar with data 1 along with data 2 inside Bar. Because it is not exceeding data 1
If data2 > data1 then draw a bar with data 1 along with data 2 top of the data1 bar. Because it is exceeding data1 and color the diff with red.

Since it can not be stacked, I am trying to show the diff in the single bar itself.

Comment: _If data2 < data1 then_ does it have to be separate colors as in the second scenario? if so, you can use a _style_ [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) -- from the link, find the section for _style_ -- then look at the example chart, see the bar for _Iron Man_ -- something like that work for you?

Comment: Thanks. Exactly i used the same. add style attribute and append color in to that.